# Dependencies of NPM local dependencies didn't resolved

Tags: node.js, npm

`node` v10.14.1
`npm` 6.4.1

I want to get rid of `package.json` in the root of my project, and split it to multiple files. So i ended with such structure:

```
`-- app
    |-- my-configs
    |-- admin
    |   `-- package.json
    `-- landings
        `-- package.json
```

But the problem is that `my-configs` is kinda dependency for `landings` and `admin`: it contains a parts of `webpack` config, and have `require()`s of `webpack` and other modules.

I've tired to `require()` it first, but `node` was failed to resolve `webpack` module.

Then i guess, that i should go with [Local Paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths), i have add `package.json` to `my-configs` with `peerDependencies`, since i want to have independent versions of `webpack` in `landings` and `admin`. But in fact it was just all the same, `node` still wanted to resolve `webpack` relative from `my-configs/base.config.js`, while i see my `@foo-internal/my-configs` in `admin/node_modules` (symlink?).

What am i doing wrong here? Is it possible to have imports from `my-configs` without explicitly set `devDependencies` in `my-configs`? I'm just get it wrong?

Comment: Adding `NODE_PATH=./node_modules ` in my scripts seems kinda "fix" issue, but feels a bit hackish and fragile

Comment: Looks like "the standard" way is using `--preserve-symlinks` flag. So my call to `webpack` should become `node  --preserve-symlinks ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli`?